# Separate TAP and HOVER tool for Edges of hv.Graph. Edge description data is missing

Tags: python, holoviews, pyviz

Trying to get hv graph with ability to tap edges separately from nodes. In my case - all meaningful data bound to edges.

```
gNodes = hv.Nodes((nodes_data.x,nodes_data.y, nodes_data.nid, nodes_data.name),\
                 vdims=['name'])

gGraph = hv.Graph(((edges_data.source, edges_data.target, edges_data.name),gNodes),vdims=['name'])

opts = dict(width=1200,height=800,xaxis=None,yaxis=None,bgcolor='black',show_grid=True)
gEdges = gGraph.edgepaths


tiles = gv.tile_sources.Wikipedia()
(tiles * gGraph.edgepaths * gGraph.nodes.opts(size=12)).opts(**opts)
```

If I use `gGraph.edgepaths  * gGraph.nodes` - where is no edge information displayed with Hover tool.
Inspection policy 'edges' for `hv.Graph` is not suitable for my task, because no single edge selection available.
Where did edge label information in edgepaths property gone? How to add it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've created separate dataframe for each link, then i grouped it by unique link label, and insert empty row between each group (two rows for edge - source and target), like in this case: [Pandas: Inserting an empty row after every 2nd row in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148170/pandas-inserting-an-empty-row-after-every-2nd-row-in-a-data-frame)

```
emty_row = pd.Series(np.NaN,edges_data.columns)
insert_f = lambda d: d.append(emty_row, ignore_index=True)
edges_df = edges_test.groupby(by='name', group_keys=False).apply(insert_f).reset_index(drop=True)
```

and create hv.EdgesPaths from df:

```
gPaths2= hv.EdgePaths(edges_df, kdims=['lon_conv_a','lat_conv_a'])
```

TAP and HOVER works fine for me.