# Adding a row of special character after every nth row (n variable but pre-decided) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to insert a row of * (any special character would do) after every n rows of my pandas data-frame. One of the SO post says it can be done using the following code:

```
s = pd.Series(0, df.columns)
f = lambda d: d.append(s, ignore_index=True)
grp = np.arange(len(df)) // 2
df= df.groupby(grp, group_keys=False).apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
```

And I am printing my final dataframe using this

```
print(final.to_string(index=False))
```

But when I tried the above code I got the  below error

```
ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

My data frame has composite numbered rows and 5 columns. Could you please help?

Also I need to get the code converted to console application(.exe)

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Basically the 1st column data is periodic, with periodicity of n. So my manager wants me to put some separator after n rows so that end users can easily see the data printed in console

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/create-pandas-dataframe-by-appending-one-row-at-a-time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148170/pandas-inserting-an-empty-row-after-every-2nd-row-in-a-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to just add a line. I used the same code you have and it works. Not sure why it is not working for you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['hello','hi','Hola','Bye','Ta','Goodbye','xyz','abc','def'],
                   'col2':[200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000]})
print (df)

s = pd.Series('', df.columns)
f = lambda d: d.append(s, ignore_index=True)
grp = np.arange(len(df)) // 3
print(df.groupby(grp, group_keys=False).apply(f).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Here's the output:

Before:

```
      col1  col2
0    hello   200
1       hi   300
2     Hola   400
3      Bye   500
4       Ta   600
5  Goodbye   700
6      xyz   800
7      abc   900
8      def  1000
```

After:

```
       col1  col2
0     hello   200
1        hi   300
2      Hola   400
3                
4       Bye   500
5        Ta   600
6   Goodbye   700
7                
8       xyz   800
9       abc   900
10      def  1000
11
```

I split it after every 4 rows with the same code (instead of `//3` I gave `//4`).

The output is:

```
       col1  col2
0     hello   200
1        hi   300
2      Hola   400
3       Bye   500
4                
5        Ta   600
6   Goodbye   700
7       xyz   800
8       abc   900
9                
10      def  1000
11
```

Comment: The issue is resolved now. Don't know why it was not happening at first attempt. Windows is weird !

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who faces the same issue in future, the final code snippet which worked for me is reproduced below. @Joe Ferndz, thanks a lot buddy.

```
num = some_user_input.count('+') + 1 # this will be used later

s = pd.Series(' ', df.columns)
def f(d): return d.append(s, ignore_index=True)
grp = np.arange(len(df)) // num
df_spaced = df.groupby(grp, group_keys=False).apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_spaced.to_string(index=False))
```