# Python pandas insert empty rows after each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello I am trying to insert 3 empty rows after each row of the current data using pandas then export the data. For example a sample current data could be:

```
name     profession
Bill      cashier
Sam        stock
Adam      security
```

Ideally what I want to achieve:

```
name     profession
Bill      cashier
Nan         Nan
Nan         Nan
Nan         Nan
Sam        stock
Nan         Nan
Nan         Nan
Nan         Nan
Adam      security
Nan         Nan
Nan         Nan
Nan         Nan
```

I have experimented with itertools however i am not sure how i can precisely get three empty rows using after each row using this method. Any help, guidance, sample would definitely be appreciative!

Comment: Here are a few examples. Stackoverflow has many examples of similar request.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148170/pandas-inserting-an-empty-row-after-every-2nd-row-in-a-data-frame), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114382/pandas-insert-alternate-blank-rows), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/create-pandas-dataframe-by-appending-one-row-at-a-time), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66380156/adding-a-row-of-special-character-after-every-nth-row-n-variable-but-pre-decide/66380501#66380501)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create pandas Dataframe by appending one row at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/create-pandas-dataframe-by-appending-one-row-at-a-time)

Comment: Very neat solution here: [Pandas insert alternate blank rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39114978/1609514).  Basically, two statements: `df.index = range(0, 4*len(df), 4); df2 = df.reindex(index=range(4*len(df)))`

Answer (score 8):

Using append on a dataframe is quite inefficient I believe (has to reallocate memory for the entire data frame each time).

DataFrames were meant for analyzing data and easily adding columns—but not rows.

So I think a good approach would be to create a new dataframe of the correct size and then transfer the data over to it.  Easiest way to do that is using an index.

```
# Demonstration data
data = 'name profession Bill cashier Sam stock Adam security'
data = np.array(data.split()).reshape((4,2))
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:],columns=data[0])

# Add n blank rows
n = 3
new_index = pd.RangeIndex(len(df)*(n+1))
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=new_index, columns=df.columns)
ids = np.arange(len(df))*(n+1)
new_df.loc[ids] = df.values
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
    name profession
0   Bill    cashier
1    NaN        NaN
2    NaN        NaN
3    NaN        NaN
4    Sam      stock
5    NaN        NaN
6    NaN        NaN
7    NaN        NaN
8   Adam   security
9    NaN        NaN
10   NaN        NaN
11   NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Efficient solution, and it is also true that you should not use append to add rows, see [Append rows to a pandas DataFrame without making a new copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23394424/11154841). Use `df.loc[0] = ...` or even better, do many row additions in just one step as was done here.

Answer (score 5):

```
 insert_rows = 3   # how many rows to insert

 df.index = range(0, insert_rows * len(df), insert_rows)

 # create new_df with added rows
 new_df = df.reindex(index = range(insert_rows * len(df)))
```

Comment: Nice answer. Note that `insert_rows` is actually "row spacing" or "number of rows to insert + 1".

Answer (score 2):

If you provided more information that would be helpful, but a thing that comes to mind is to use this command

```
df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True)
```

This will add an empty row to your data frame, though as you can see you have to pass set `ignore_index=True`, otherwise the append won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The code below includes a function to add empty rows between the existing rows of a dataframe.

Might not be the best approach for what you want to do, it might be better to add the blank rows when you are exporting the data.

```
import pandas as pd

def add_blank_rows(df, no_rows):
    df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    for idx in range(len(df)):
        df_new = df_new.append(df.iloc[idx])
        for _ in range(no_rows):
            df_new=df_new.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True)
    return df_new
    
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

df_with_blank_rows = add_blank_rows(df, 3)

print(df_with_blank_rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

this works

```py
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df_new = df_new.append(row)
    for _ in range(3):
        df_new = df_new.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True)
```

`df` of course is the original DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to do that with one loop:

```
def NAN_rows(df):
    row = df.shape[0]
    x = np.empty((3,2,)) # 3 empty row and 2 columns. You can increase according to your original df
    x[:] = np.nan
    df_x = pd.DataFrame( columns = ['name' ,'profession'])
    for i in range(row):
        temp = np.vstack([df.iloc[i].tolist(),x])
        df_x = pd.concat([df_x, pd.DataFrame(temp,columns = ['name' ,'profession'])], axis=0)
        
    return df_x
   
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'name' : ['Bill','Sam','Adam'],
    'profession' : ['cashier','stock','security']
})

print(NAN_rows(df))

#Output: 

   name profession
0  Bill    cashier
1   nan        nan
2   nan        nan
3   nan        nan
0   Sam      stock
1   nan        nan
2   nan        nan
3   nan        nan
0  Adam   security
1   nan        nan
2   nan        nan
3   nan        nan
```