# Add blank row to a pandas dataframe after every period

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that is quite similar to this:-

| name | status |
| --- | --- |
| eric | single |
| . | 0 |
| xavier | couple |
| sarah | couple |
| . | 0 |
| aaron | divorced |
| . | 0 |

I would like to add a new row after every period as below:-

| name | status |
| --- | --- |
| eric | single |
| . | 0 |
|  |  |
| xavier | couple |
| sarah | couple |
| . | 0 |
|  |  |
| aaron | divorced |
| . | 0 |
|  |  |

Appreciate any guidance on this!

Comment: does this work ?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66466080/python-pandas-insert-empty-rows-after-each-row

Comment: Hi, nope I've tried that before but fortunately the answer provided below works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and apply a concatenation of each group to a dummy row:

```
(df
 .groupby(df['name'].shift().eq('.').cumsum(), group_keys=False)
 .apply(lambda g: pd.concat([g, pd.DataFrame(index=[0], columns=g.columns)]).fillna(''))
)
```

output:

```
     name    status
0    eric    single
1       .         0
0                  
2  xavier    couple
3   sarah    couple
4       .         0
0                  
5   aaron  divorced
6       .         0
0
```

Or extract the rows with `.` and concat:

```
df2 = df[df['name'].eq('.')].copy()
df2.loc[:] = ''
pd.concat([df, df2]).sort_index(kind='stable')
```

output:

```
     name    status
0    eric    single
1       .         0
1                  
2  xavier    couple
3   sarah    couple
4       .         0
4                  
5   aaron  divorced
6       .         0
6
```