# Adding more than one empty row between pandas groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, xlwings

I want to add several empty rows between each groupby in my pandas dataframe. I know similar questions have been asked in the past but all of the answers I could find rely on the recently discontinued append function. I think I am close but I cannot get it to work.

From what I've read, the idea is for the concat function to replace append so I have been trying to 1) Make my groups, 2) Make a blank dataframe with the correct columns and number of rows, then 3) Loop through the groups and concatenate them individually with the blank dataframe. This looked something like:

Current df:

```
    column1    column2    column3
0      a          1        blue
1      b          2        blue
2      a          1        green
3      b          2        green
4      a          1        black
5      b          2        black
```

What I expect:

```
    column1    column2    column3
0      a          1        blue
1      b          2        blue
0
1
2
3
4
2      a          1        green
3      b          2        green
0
1
2
3
4
4      a          1        black
5      b          2        black
```

###### What I tried:

```
# Create my groups by the desired column
dfg = df.groupby("column3")

# Create my blank df with the same columns as my main df and with the desired number of blank rows
blank_df5 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['column1','column2','column3'],index=['0','1','2','3','4'])

# Loop through and concatenate groups and the blank df
for colors in dfg:
    pd.concat([colors, blank_df5], ignore_index=True)

print(dfg)
```

This returned: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'tuple'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

I then tried making the groups into their own dfs and then looping through that like:

```
dfg = df.groupby('column1')
[dfg.get_group(x) for x in dfg.groups]

blank_df5 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['column1','column2','column3'],index=['0','1','2','3','4'])

for colors in dfg:
    pd.concat([colors, blank_df5], ignore_index=True)

# I also tried [pd.concat([colors, blank_df5], ignore_index=True) for column3 in dfw] with the same result
```

result was still: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'tuple'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Other things I've tried:**

```
mask = df['column3'].ne(df['column3'].shift(-1))
df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=mask.index[mask] + .5, columns=df.columns)

dfg = pd.concat([df,df1]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:-1]

print(dfg)
```

This works to add one empty row in-between the groups, but I can't get it to add more than that.

```
dfg = (pd.concat([df, 
            df.groupby('column3').apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1).iloc[-1]).reset_index()])
           .sort_values('column3')
           .reset_index(drop=True))

print(dfg)
```

This returns: ValueError: cannot insert column3, already exists

```
dfg = df.groupby('column1')

for colors in dfg:
        new_rows = 5
        new_index = pd.RangeIndex(len(colors)*(new_rows+1))
        dfg = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=new_index, columns=df.columns)
        ids = np.arange(len(colors))*(new_rows+1)
        dfg.loc[ids] = df.values

print(dfg)
```

This returns: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (710,) into shape (2,)
If I remove the loop and just run what is in the loop it adds the empty rows in-between each row of data.

Hopefully this makes sense, thank you in advance for any help.

If anyone is curious, the reason I need to do this is to dump it into excel, it's a company decision, not mine.

Comment: when looping over the groups you have the group name and then the group itself (df) in a Tuple. Add a variable to the for loop: `for a, b in df.groupby...`

Comment: Sorry, I may just be dense but in my example isn't "colors" in `for colors in dfg:` the variable?

Comment: no, `for color_name, colors in dfg` notice the comma and 2 vars between `for` and `in`. You're not dense. It's a normal question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your 2nd approach :

```
N = 5

grps = df.groupby("column3", sort=False)

out = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.concat([g, pd.DataFrame("", index=range(N), columns=df.columns)])
        if i < len(grps)-1 else g for i, (_, g) in enumerate(grps)
    ]
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  column1 column2 column3
0       a       1    blue
1       b       2    blue
0                        
1                        
2                        
3                        
4                        
2       a       1   green
3       b       2   green
0                        
1                        
2                        
3                        
4                        
4       a       1   black
5       b       2   black

[16 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try appending blank rows after every color, but appending is an inefficient problem.

Looking at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66466080/python-pandas-insert-empty-rows-after-each-row) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114382/pandas-insert-alternate-blank-rows), I find the below code to be a better solution. Note I'm assuming that the group of colors are always in blocks of 2, you will have to change the code if that is not true.

```
import numpy as np
# create an empty dataframe with the required numbers of rows first
n = 3 # num of blank rows to add
new_index = pd.RangeIndex(len(df)/2*(n+1))
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=new_index, columns=df.columns)

# fill it with original data frame values at the required indices:

arr = np.arange(0,len(new_df), step=n+2),np.arange(1,len(new_df), step=n+2)
ids = np.sort(np.concatenate(arr))
new_df.loc[ids] = df.values
new_df
```

Output:

```
   column1  column2 column3
0        a      1.0    blue
1        b      2.0    blue
2      NaN      NaN     NaN
3      NaN      NaN     NaN
4      NaN      NaN     NaN
5        a      1.0   green
6        b      2.0   green
7      NaN      NaN     NaN
8      NaN      NaN     NaN
9      NaN      NaN     NaN
10       a      1.0   black
11       b      2.0   black
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified in my example. My groups all have unknown and inconsistent numbers of rows. I can't think of a way to account for this in your code. You are right though, if they contained consistent amounts of data this would work beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses [`offset`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api/range.html#xlwings.Range.offset) of xlwings to jump over 5 rows before inserting the next dataframe (to create the space between the dataframes). This way you don't need `pd.concat()`.

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

path = r"test.xlsx"

df1 = pd._testing.makeDataFrame()  # or df1 = df.loc[df["column3"]=="blue"]
df2 = pd._testing.makeDataFrame()  # or df2 = df.loc[df["column3"]=="green"]
df3 = pd._testing.makeDataFrame()  # or df3 = df.loc[df["column3"]=="black"]

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

with xw.App(visible=False):
    wb = xw.Book()
    ws = wb.sheets[0]
    for df in dfs:
        ws.used_range[-1:,:].offset(row_offset=6).value = df  # Use row_offset=6 to create 5 empty rows.
    ws["1:6"].delete()  # This is just to delete the first 6 rows, which are empty.

    wb.save(path)
    wb.close()
```